# Isolated vertex bug in breadth-first-search

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I have found an implementation for bfs_visited (returns all the nodes that the breadth first search algorithm has reached) from here: 
http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/

```
def bfs(graph, start):
    visited, queue = set(), [start]
    while queue:
        vertex = queue.pop(0)
        if vertex not in visited:
            visited.add(vertex)
            queue.extend(graph[vertex] - visited)
    return visited

bfs(graph, 'A') # {'B', 'C', 'A', 'F', 'D', 'E'}
```

And it works fine with this representation of a graph:

```
graph1 = {'A': set(['B', 'C']),
     'B': set(['A', 'D', 'E']),
     'C': set(['A', 'F']),
     'D': set(['B']),
     'E': set(['B', 'F']),
     'F': set(['C', 'E'])}
```

But I want to use this implementation instead:

```
graph2 = { 1: set([2]),                    # changed
    2: set([1, 3, 4]),
    3: set([2, 4]),
    4: set([2, 3]),
    5: set([]),
            6: set([5])}
```

And this works almost fine:

```
>>> bfs_visited(graph2, graph2[1])
set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

except in the case of an isolated vertex, where it returns an empty set, instead of 
a set with a single element:

```
>>> bfs_visited(graph2, graph2[5])
set([])
```

Is there a way to take set([5]) as output in the case above with the second representation?

Comment: Yes, you could work out what the code is doing and modify it to do what you want instead.

Comment: I have worked with 4 different implementions of bfs so far, I know how it works.
The problem is that when I put graph2[5] as the second argument, I
access an empty set, from where there is no turning back to the respective key (5 in the case above).

Answer (score 1):

First, you are inconsistent, either use strings in both keys and values or integers, do not mix them

> ```
> graph2 = { '1': set(['2']),
>            '2': set(['1', '3', '4']),
>            '3': set(['2', '4']),
>            '4': set(['2', '3', '6']),
>            '5': set([]),
>            '6': set(['4'])}
> ```

second, your bfs accepts **vertices names**, not their neighbourhoods, so you should call

> bfs(graph2, '5') #correct

not

> bfs(graph2, graph2['5']) #incorrect

and it works like a charm

> ```
> >>> bfs(graph2, '2') 
> set(['1', '3', '2', '4', '6'])
> >>> bfs(graph2, '5') 
> set(['5'])
> ```

Comment: I'm really sorry but this is the representation I need to use, I have just changed it:
graph2 = { 1: set([2]),                    # changed
  2: set([1, 3, 4]),
  3: set([2, 4]),
  4: set([2, 3]),
  5: set([]),
                6: set([5])}

I know that this works:
graph2 = { '1': set(['2']),
           '2': set(['1', '3', '4']),
           '3': set(['2', '4']),
           '4': set(['2', '3', '6']),
           '5': set([]),
           '6': set(['4'])}

I have tried that too.